# Is using register type variable in kernel bad?

Tags: c, kernel

I was reading [Calling Convention by Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf). In chapter 5, he talks about registers where he points out that it is a bad idea to use registers in kernel code.

Does that also imply that using a variables with keyword `register` in `C` when programming kernel also a bad idea?

Comment: Since the library for a tool set is usually OS dependent, the internal calling convention for the kernel is between the library and the kernel, not between a program and the library, so it shouldn't matter to the programmer. One exception is old code running in 16 bit real mode like BIOS or MSDOS calls that use registers and an INT to "call" BIOS or MSDOS functions or a few other OS versions.

Comment: The linked text actually talks about vector and floating point registers. These are not normally used by kernel code (unless you instruct your compiler to do so). The text just says that if you decide to use these registers for whatever reason, you are yourself responsible to save and restore them - with the consequences this implies: you'll make your code uninterruptible, effectively suppressing preemption (which will likely cause lags), so this decision should be carefully considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this does not imply that using `register` keyword in kernel-mode C code is a bad idea: the keyword is only a hint, not an order, to the compiler<sup>*</sup>. In the end, it is the compiler who picks what storage to use for what variables. When you tell the compiler that you are compiling kernel-mode code by passing an appropriate flag (on Windows that would be `/kernel`) the compiler knows which registers it must not use, so it wouldn't place your variables into these registers, even when you request `register` storage for the variables.

With that said, using `register` is unlikely to give you much benefit these days: modern optimizing compilers are really good at picking the optimal use of registers, making it very hard to improve upon their allocation by providing allocation hints through the `register` keyword.

<sup>*</sup> It's actually even worse than that: when you use `register` keyword, you promise compiler that you are not going to take an address of the variable that you declared `register`. So the contract becomes binding on you, but not on the compiler. Thanks, [Jens Gustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt), for pointing this out.

Comment: `register` isn't even a hint. The only difference that the c standard gives to it is that you are not allowed to take the address (`&`) of such a variable. So it is not more than a contract that binds *you* and not the compiler.

Comment: @JensGustedt Thanks for pointing this out! I added a note to the answer.

Comment: I think the original post may have be thinking of fast call convention, where some parameters are passed in registers. This is mostly an issue for 32 bit mode, since at least Microsoft compilers only have a fast call model for X64 mode.